# Touch Gesture for the entire screen

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am new to writing programs for windows. Apologies, if my question is a very easy or basic one.

I am trying to write a code which uses the touch gesture api's provided by Microsoft for windows 10 using C++. I am using a touch screen monitor too.

I was able to create a window and a handle to that to use the touch gesture as mentioned in the code below:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

LRESULT CALLBACK DecodeGesture(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.

    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

                                        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );


    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {   
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_GESTURE:
        // Insert handler code here to interpret the gesture.            
        return DecodeGesture(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT DecodeGesture(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // Create a structure to populate and retrieve the extra message info.

    GESTUREINFO gi;

    ZeroMemory(&gi, sizeof(GESTUREINFO));

    gi.cbSize = sizeof(GESTUREINFO);

    BOOL bResult = GetGestureInfo((HGESTUREINFO)lParam, &gi);
    BOOL bHandled = FALSE;

    if (bResult) {
        // now interpret the gesture
        switch (gi.dwID) {
        case GID_ZOOM:
            // Code for zooming goes here     
            bHandled = TRUE;
            break;
        case GID_PAN:
            // Code for panning goes here
            bHandled = TRUE;
            break;
        case GID_ROTATE:
            // Code for rotation goes here
            bHandled = TRUE;
            break;
        case GID_TWOFINGERTAP:
        {
            // Code for two-finger tap goes here
            // Get all instances of the onscreen keyboard running on the local computer.
            // This will return an empty array if onscreen keyboard isn't running.
            array<Process^>^localByName = Process::GetProcessesByName("osk");
            if (localByName->Length < 1)
            {
                system("start powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \n");
                system("start powershell.exe osk");
                //system("pause");
            }
            bHandled = TRUE;
            break;
        }
        case GID_PRESSANDTAP:
            // Code for roll over goes here
            bHandled = TRUE;
            break;
        default:
            // A gesture was not recognized
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr > 0) {
            //MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Error!", L"Could not retrieve a GESTUREINFO structure.", MB_OK);
        }
    }
    if (bHandled) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Clearly, the above mentioned code points to a handle, that is a window and not the entire screen.

How can I modify this code to create a handle that will point to the entire screen and not just the area inside that window?

Comment: _"a handle that will point to the entire Operating System"_ Huh, what please?

Comment: By entire operating system, I mean the entire User Interface and not the area occupied by the created window.

Comment: _The desktop_ in other words?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Yeah the desktop

Comment: Why do you want access to these things? as an example, what would you want to control the Start Menu for?

Comment: I don't think its a XY problem. I was unable to find any information about this. I have searched a lot. So I asked for help

Comment: X-Y problem means I'm asking about problem X, but what I really need is a solution to problem Y and I (possibly wrongly) think that solution is X.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: If you notice the Function Decode gesture, there is a case of Two FInger tap, where I am making the on screen keyboard appear. And there is no system defined functionality for a two finger tap. I want to add some functionalities like that. But this action seems to work only inside the created window.

Comment: So you want to do a two finger tap _anywhere_ on the screen, so that an onscreen keyboard pops up? So this is an XY problem...

Comment: Yeah anywhere on the screen. So if there was any way to create a handle that points to anywhere on the screen, that would be helpful for me. I am just asking for a direction. Not hand feeding

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I was thinking that maybe certain areas of this code can be edited or removed to make that happen. So I am trying to edit the solution for problem X

Comment: `array<Process^>^localByName` isn't C++ code. Please update the question with appropriate tags. Besides, there is no solution for the problem you are trying to solve. What would happen, if two programs did this?

Comment: @IInspectable: That is a working code currently running in my Visual Studio 2017. Its a C++ Windows Desktop application. And array<Process^>^localByName is not giving me any errors or warnings. You might have to configure certain properties to run it. If you need help with that, I can provide that

Comment: @IInspectable: You have a valid point there regarding 2 programs doing that. Well in my scenario, 2 programs won't be doing it.
You can try running it using the following headers:

#using <System.dll>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sys\types.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;

The compiler might ask you to enable /clr and disable some other properties.

Comment: `#using` is not a C++ directive. In case you are using C++/CLI, you should update your question. It strikes me as odd, that a developer doesn't know, what programming language they are using. C++/CLI is not C++. Likewise, C++/CX is not C++.